# Strange looking region of France on Google Maps

Tags: france, factoids, identify-this

I was idly browsing on google maps and came across this area on the Atlantic coast of France.

The terrain looks intriguing. What is it, any idea? They look like water bodies. But the shapes are not the typical natural outlines but more like a manmade pool. The region does not seem like a natural swamp and there's lots of roads through it etc.

Any idea?
[image]

Comment: If you look in satellite view and street view, you can see the salt pans. Someone spent a lot of time tracing out everything for Google Maps, but it doesn't look quite as dramatic in the actual photographs.

Comment: @ZachLipton Yes. The satellite image looks very different.

Comment: Satellite view : https://www.google.fr/maps/@46.9586061,-2.0075154,1965m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: Street view : https://www.google.fr/maps/@46.9586061,-2.0075154,15z

Comment: @ZachLipton Have a feeling Google may well have mostly automated this tracing, I'm thinking.

Comment: "Someone spent a lot of time tracing " that's largely automated now, Zach

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a region with five main features in the marshes, that you can even see in Google Street View:

- *prés salés* (salt meadows) in the part of the map that you captured, [like here to the left of your map](https://www.google.fr/maps/@46.9599613,-2.0268145,3a,75y,121.65h,94.66t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sLofow2r2u9oCMEdMntQpBw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656), [here in the middle](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Le+P%C3%A2tis,+85230+Bouin/@46.9602013,-2.0078218,3a,75y,303h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s5vTlYGC1A_8i8KxcxKfLsQ!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D5vTlYGC1A_8i8KxcxKfLsQ%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D303.8588%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x480507d4e35a1351:0x5075d037f5ff195b!8m2!3d46.960358!4d-2.002538) or [here to the top-right corner](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Le+P%C3%A2tis,+85230+Bouin/@46.9677237,-1.9838448,3a,75y,122.7h,108.17t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sv0ftNIfZxx3IGmKkxnRz8A!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo2.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3Dv0ftNIfZxx3IGmKkxnRz8A%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D30.82109%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x480507d4e35a1351:0x5075d037f5ff195b!8m2!3d46.960358!4d-2.002538) ([satellite view here](https://www.google.fr/maps/@46.9586061,-2.0075154,1965m/data=!3m1!1e3)), between former salt ponds;

[image: salt meadow 1]
[image: salt meadow 2]
[image: salt meadow 3]
[image: salt meadow (sat view)]

> Have you seen the cows in the first photo?

- salt farming that used to take place in basins between the salt meadows, fed by seawater canals ([*étiers*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tier), you can see their names on the map), but isn't done anymore in the part of the map you found (part of the village of Bouin, which used to be an island and got silted, forming the marshes around it converted to salt farming); to the north [you can see some here](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Les+Evins,+85230/@46.9723373,-2.0207692,3a,43y,156.44h,93.42t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sawNrMNPQNGqkwMV6G2iPeg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x4805088fd0e3ac19:0xb44634204f4ded22!8m2!3d46.974503!4d-2.015625) ([satellite view](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Les+Evins,+85230/@46.9720354,-2.0184286,373m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4805088fd0e3ac19:0xb44634204f4ded22!8m2!3d46.974503!4d-2.015625)) which are the last sites in Bouin, which [used to have 700 of them](http://www.sel-vendee.fr/#section-292); other parts of the marshes (*[Marais Breton](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marais_breton)*) even [don't get fed with seawater anymore](http://www.sel-vendee.fr/le-marais-breton/);

[image: salt farming]
[image: salt farming (sat view)]

> Have you seen the small dikes inside the ponds that are still used? They disappear when the salt pond gets abandoned.

- fishing (*[pêcheries](http://www.paysdugois.fr/les-pecheries/)*) in the seawater canals [like here](https://www.google.fr/maps/@46.8958105,-2.0643986,3a,75y,109.52h,87.04t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s4dUzuqoWV8k24awb5CS5yw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1) ([satellite view here](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Le+Grand+Pont,+85230+Beauvoir-sur-Mer/@46.8952351,-2.0612661,374m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4805046d12783d19:0xcd4292814c330ceb!8m2!3d46.895344!4d-2.0646105)),

[image: fisheries]
[image: fisheries (sat view)]

> Have you seen the huts along the canal?

- closer to the coast, polders with oyster farming (*ostréiculture*) [like here](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Le+P%C3%A2tis,+85230+Bouin/@46.9431496,-2.0597193,3a,60y,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1shC1CGNDTdAVbNdeR4QZipg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x480507d4e35a1351:0x5075d037f5ff195b!8m2!3d46.960358!4d-2.002538) ([satellite view here](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Le+P%C3%A2tis,+85230+Bouin/@46.943747,-2.0626557,771m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x480507d4e35a1351:0x5075d037f5ff195b!8m2!3d46.960358!4d-2.002538)) where some seem to specialize in the  oyster larvae ([*naissains*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naissain)) that will then grow further somewhere else;

[image: polders]
[image: polders]

> When zooming you'll see the [oyster bags](http://www.bys.fr/poches-ostreicoles-huitres-ostreiculture) from above (dark green zones in the ponds).

- salt farming basins converted to oyster farming can be found further north (e.g. [here – only satellite view](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/44580+Bourgneuf-en-Retz/@47.0436746,-1.9868546,178m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4805a0b44219afeb:0x772850a0f14226d9!8m2!3d47.042904!4d-1.953453)) – compare to [salt farming here](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/44580+Bourgneuf-en-Retz/@47.0399817,-1.9731091,3a,60y,270.44h,84.41t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1snoNI_NnvAnxh68WhMDIkqg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x4805a0b44219afeb:0x772850a0f14226d9!8m2!3d47.042904!4d-1.953453) ([satellite view](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/44580+Bourgneuf-en-Retz/@47.0396238,-1.9769106,337m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4805a0b44219afeb:0x772850a0f14226d9!8m2!3d47.042904!4d-1.953453)).

[image: oyster farming (sat view)]

> See the oyster bags there too.

[image: salt pond]
[image: salt pond (sat view)]

> Compare with the former and actual salt ponds.

Comment: Looks like Holland.

Answer (score 73):

In a curious coincidence, there was [a question about this part of France](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/94298) just a few hours ago.

You are looking at the [Noirmoutier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noirmoutier) area of France, which in the past was one of the world's premier regions for the production of [Fleur de Sel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleur_de_sel):

> a salt that forms as a thin, delicate crust on the surface of seawater as it evaporates.

It is produced thus:

> One method of gathering sea salt is to draw seawater into marsh basins or salt pans and allow the water to evaporate, leaving behind the salt that was dissolved in it. As the water evaporates, most of the salt precipitates out on the bottom of the marsh or pan (and is later collected as ordinary sea salt), but some salt crystals float on the surface of the water, forming a delicate crust of intricate pyramidal crystals. This is ***fleur de sel***.

The map you include in your question shows **salt pans**. For more on this intriguing topic, I can heartily recommend 'Salt: A World History' by Mark Kurlansky, available from the usual booksellers.

Tourism forms a major part of the economy of Noirmoutier these days, and you will find many places willing to sell you some genuine Noirmoutier *fleur de sel*.

---

However, as pointed out by [peufeu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/61957/peufeu), the *particular* area you show may in fact not contain salt pans (although there are a lot in the area) - what is shown here may be oyster ponds for in-shore shellfish farming, another activity common in the area.

[This tourism info page](http://www.vendee-tourism.co.uk/discover/nature-and-countryside/the-marais-breton/) about the area includes this image of a fishery:

[image: "Fishery"]

and the text

> In the sheltered waters of the bay, in-shore fishing and oyster
>   farming are important industries in the small communities of Bouin and
>   Beauvoir sur Mer.

Also, compare and contrast this picture of salt-farming:

[image: salt farming]

and this picture of oyster farming:

[image: oyster farming]

both from another tourism site for the area. The more irregular water features you're asking about seem more like the latter.

Still read the salt book, though :)

Comment: A curious coincidence? I beg to differ - More than likely the asker saw that other question and looked up the area on Google Maps.

Comment: I have been to this part of France several times, and even once bought a a jar of this salt as a gift :-)

Comment: even if that's the explanation, it's still a curious coincidence!  (with an explanation)  Well done, Sherlock!  and yeah, it's the only salt to use!

Comment: Not sure about them being salt pans (the shape is different, see here https://goo.gl/maps/UHNzVXttbyw). I suggest saltwater ponds used for oyster farming, there is a lot of it going on in this region.

Comment: +1 for the Kurlansky recommendation. The audiobook is great.

Comment: @peufeu you make a good point. Updating the answer appropriately.

Comment: @peufeu: It's not oyster farming, only abandoned salt ponds (there used to be 700 of them in the small village of Bouin alone). See my answer for more details.

Comment: The fishery picture is not for oysters, it's done in the canals feeding the salt ponds.

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at some of the canals or ditches on [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Le+Pont+Gu%C3%A9rineau,+85230+Bouin,+France/@46.9595289,-2.0087032,3a,60y,174.45h,79.42t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sX8d6ZHAG4NfoIxZWk0CYJQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x48050629a429c8a1:0xcd7889942ed58080!8m2!3d46.9607699!4d-2.0116299).

Some background on *sel de fleur* from Mark Kurlansky's excellent history of salt:

[image]